# Remove oldest entry in Map() with O(1) time complexity JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hashmap

If we want to keep fixed size of a map - 3 entries and remove oldest touched entry, when new one is created, how do we do it with constant time? (I got told it's possible)

If we do such operations:

```
let cache = new Map()

cache.set('one', 1);
cache.set('two', 2);
cache.set('three', 3);

cache.set('two', 'two');

cache.set('four', 4);
```

I'd expect map then to be:

```
{
    ['three', 3],
    ['two', 'two'],
    ['four', 4],
}
```

I can think only of having O(n) solution for invalidation, but it defeats whole purpose of cache.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: looking for a key in for loop :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are iterated in the order in which the keys were created. So you can use that to do

```
const cache = new Map();
const keysIter = cache.keys();
function set(key, value) {
    cache.set(key, value);
    if (cache.size > 3) {
        cache.delete(keysIter.next().value);
    }
}
```

If however by "oldest touched" you want to refer to updates, not just to creation (e.g. in your example, `cache.set('five', 5)` would evict `['three', 3]` not `['two', 'two']`), you will need to keep track of these touches yourself, e.g. in a circular buffer. Or maybe just call  `cache.delete(key)` every time before "updating", so that the `cache.set(key, value)` always creates a new entry at the end.

Comment: Didn't think that instead of updating I can delete, I guess it's more efficient than having circular buffer or other way of updating.

Comment: Also I think you should delete by key, not value

Comment: @LizardDerad I'm not deleting by value. The `.value` of the `keysIter.next()` result is a key of the `cache` map.